# what is the difference between assert and a if condition embedded with a raise

Tags: python, assert

i am currently learning about the assert statement in python and i cant seem to understand its main usage and what seperates it from simply raising an exception. if i wrote an if statement along with my condition and simply raised an exception if the condition is not met, how is that different from using the assert statement?

```
def times_ten(number):
    return number * 100
 
result = times_ten(20)
assert result == 200, 'Expected times_ten(20) to return 200, instead got ' + str(result)
```

to me both codes do the same thing

```
def times_ten(number):
    return number * 100
 
result = times_ten(20)
if  result != 200:
    raise Exception('Expected times_ten(20) to return 200, instead got ' + str(result))
```

Comment: A failed `assert` will raise an `AssertionError`, which may or may not be the closest semantic meaning you want to convey to the caller. See the list of [concrete exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#concrete-exceptions). Maybe it is more meaningful to raise a `ValueError` or `IndexError`, etc.

Comment: `assert` statements are also only effective when `__debug__` is set to true, which means you can disable them at runtime without modifying the code. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) provides the equivalent `if` statements to an `assert` statement.

```
assert expression
```

is the same as

```
if __debug__:
    if not expression:
        raise AssertionError()
```

while

```
assert expression1, expression2
```

is the same as

```
if __debug__:
    if not expression1:
        raise AssertionError(expression2)
```

As you can see, it's an `AssertionError`, not a generic `Exception`, that is raised when the condition is false, and there is a guard that can be set to `False` on startup (using the `-O` option) to prevent the assertion from being checked at all.